# Multiple threads update same row in database at a time how to maintain consistence

Tags: java, database, multithreading, hibernate, concurrency

In my java application multiple threads update same row at a time how to get consistence results ?

for example

```
current row value count =0; 
thread 1 updating it to count+1=1;
thread 2 updating at the same time count+1=2

    but it should not happen like this 
    thread 1 updating it to count+1=1;
    thread 2 updating at the same time count+1=1;

    both threads should not catch the same value because both are running same time 


    how can we achieve this in jdbc  hibernate , database ??
```

Comment: How many entities are each thread updating within a single database transaction?

Comment: one entity as of now but may vary

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly handle two threads updating the same row in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38303012/how-to-properly-handle-two-threads-updating-the-same-row-in-a-database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible ways to go.

- Either you choose a pessimistic approach and lock rows, tables or even ranges of rows.
- Or you work with versioned Entities (Optimistic Locking).

Maybe you can will find more information here:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html

Answer (score 1):

Incrementing a counter in this way is hard to manage concurrently.  You really need to use pessimistic locking to solve this particular problem.

```
SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE x IS TRUE FOR UPDATE
```

This will force each thread to wait until the previous one commits before it reads the counter.

This is necessary because you have two potential issues, the first is the *read* race and the second is the *write* lock.  The write lock gets taken automatically in most RDBMSs but unless you take it explicitly before you read, the counter will be incremented *once* by both threads together (because both read the original value before the update).

If you need to have parallel writes, then you need to *insert* a table and then materialize an aggregate later.  That is a more complex design pattern though.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not 100% clear, but I guess you're looking for the different locking strategies: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#locking

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on a DB that has sequence generators (Oracle, Postgres, ...) you should consider using those.  Assuming you're always doing the same increment value and it's no that one thread increments by one and another by two then that should be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a detailed answer to this question: 
[How to properly handle two threads updating the same row in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38303012/how-to-properly-handle-two-threads-updating-the-same-row-in-a-database/38444458#38444458)

To summarize:

The biggest question is: Are the two threads trying to persist the same data ?To summarize the content of the linked answer. Lets name the two threads T1 and T2. There are couple of aproaches:

**Approach 1**, this is more or less the **last to update Wins** situation. It more or less avoids the optimistic locking (the version counting). In case you don't have dependency from T1 to T2 or reverse in order to set status PARSED. This should be good.

**Aproach 2 Optimistic Locking** This is what you have now. The solution is to refresh the data and restart your operation.

**Aproach 3 Row level DB lock** The solution here is more or less the same as for approach 2 with the small correction that the Pessimistic lock dure. The main difference is that in this case it may be a READ lock and you might not be even able to read the data from the database in order to refresh it if it is PESSIMISTIC READ.

**Aproach 4 application level synchronization** There are many different ways to do synchronization. One example would be to actually arrange all your updates in a BlockingQueue or JMS queue(if you want it to be persistent) and push all updates from a single thread. To visualize it a bit T1 and T2 will put elements on the Queue and there will be a single T3 thread reading operations and pushing them to the Database server.